# Which would make a Class file bigger? import java.awt.*, or a bunch or single import statements?

Tags: java, class, import, size

Okay, so if I had a project that used:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;
```

Would it make the Class file smaller to use:

```
import java.awt.*
```

I'm thinking against it because I'm importing a lot of things I don't need. I'm thinking for it cause it makes the file have a lot less characters.

Comment: This trips up a lot of people who are moving from C/C++ to Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No difference. These are a compile-time construct only.

Answer (score 14):

No, there is no difference at all.

According to [The Java Virtual Machine Specifications, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html), [Chapter 5: Loading, Linking and Initializing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html) says the following:

> The Java virtual machine dynamically
>   loads (§2.17.2), links (§2.17.3), and
>   initializes (§2.17.4) classes and
>   interfaces. Loading is the process of
>   finding the binary representation of a
>   class or interface type with a
>   particular name and creating a class
>   or interface from that binary
>   representation. Linking is the process
>   of taking a class or interface and
>   combining it into the runtime state of
>   the Java virtual machine so that it
>   can be executed.

At compile time, there are no linking of classes, therefore, using wildcards for `import`ing makes no difference. Other classes are not included together into the resulting `class` file.

In fact, if you look at the bytecode of the `class` file (via [`javap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) or such disassembler), you won't find any `import` statements, so having more or less numbers of `import` statements in your source won't affect the size of the `class` file.

Here's a simple experiment: Try writing a program, and compiling with `import`s using wildcards, and another one with explicit imports. The resulting `class` file should be the same size.

---

Using explicit `import` statements on specific classes are perhaps less readable (and troublesome, if one doesn't use an IDE like Eclipse which will write it for you), but will allow you to deal with overlaps of class names in two packages.

For example, there is a `List` class in both the [`java.util`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`java.awt`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) packages. By importing both packages, there will be a conflict for the class named `List`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

// ... snip ... //

List l;    // which "List" are we talking about?
```

By only importing the specific classes you need, these conflicts could be somewhat avoided:

```
import java.util.Hashmap;
import java.awt.List;

// .. snip ... //
List l;    // Now we know for sure it's java.awt.List
```

Of course, if you had to use both `java.util.List` and `java.awt.List` then you're out of luck; you'll need to explicitly use their fully-qualified class names.

Answer (score 3):

The Java `import` statement does not add any size to the class file. It allows the compiler to deduce what names refer to at compile time.

The only difference the line

```
import java.util.*;
```

makes is that you can write:

```
Set<String> set;
```

rather than:

```
java.util.Set<String> set;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, be sure to look at my "Import on Demand is Evil!" article:

http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html

You should ***never*** use the * syntax! It can cause your program to stop compiling when code is *added* to another library!

Now here's how import really works:

When you say

```
import a.b.c.Foo;
```

all this does is tell the compiler that when you say "Foo", you really mean "a.b.c.Foo". The compiler will then replace all occurences of Foo with a.b.c.Foo in the generated bytecode.

When you say

```
import a.b.c.*;
```

this tells the compiler "when you see a symbol XXX you don't recognize, check to see if there is an a.b.c.XXX" If found, the compiler will replace XXX with a.b.c.XXX in the generated bytecode.

If more than one "*" import matches an unknown symbol, you'll get a compiler error for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Java only  includes that stuff you really need... So there won't be any difference in the final compiled version using one or the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, why do you care about the size of your class file ?

It is a better practice to explicitly include all classes needed instead of doing a "import foo.bar.*".

That makes your code more readable, and more maintainable.

Comment: Some applications have size constraints.

Answer (score 1):

No change at all in the generated class file.

Imports only have influence on the compiler (which might take a little bit longer if it has to index a lot of directories) and, of course, on the source code (which is IMO more maintainable when you can see exactly which classes are used).

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested in making the size of the class smaller, [the game making competition java4k](http://www.java4k.com/index.php?action=view&page=getstarted) has some tips, e.g., this page http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/java4k-tips/java4k-tips.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference as stated in previous posts, however as a preference I use
strict importing as I find it makes in my opinion the code more pleasent to read

Answer (score 0):

In complement to earlier answers, the only difference you should see is that the compiling should be a *bit* faster, when you explicitly tell what you want `import`ed, instead of giving a wildcard, that can include thousands (upon thousands) of unnecessary packages and classes.