# What's the difference between import java.util.*; and import java.util.Date; ?

Tags: java, import

I just want to output current and I wrote

```
import java.util.*;
```

at beginning, and

```
System.out.println(new Date());
```

in the main part.

But what I got was something like this:

```
Date@124bbbf
```

When I change the import to `import java.util.Date;` the code works perfectly, why?

====================================

The problem was, OK, my source file was "Date.java", that's the cause.

Well, it is all my fault, I confused everybody around ;P

And thanks to everyone below. It's really NICE OF YOU ;)

Comment: In you first example, do you perchance import anything else? E.g. java.sql.Date?

Comment: You could have other imports - let us see some compilable code that shows this

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187453/import-package-vs-import-package-specifictype, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585268/which-would-make-a-class-file-bigger-import-java-awt-or-a-bunch-or-single-imp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553909/is-there-any-difference-between-class-imports-and-package-imports-in-java

Comment: Voting up because sometimes a good counter-example is as helpful as anything. :)

Comment: thx you all 
@Mark i named the class "Date" and that's the problem
@finnw thx for quoting
@mtruesdell pity, i can not voting yet.. a very newbie here i am

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably have some other "Date" class imported somewhere (or you have a Date class in you package, which does not need to be imported). With "import java.util.*" you are using the "other" Date. In this case it's best to explicitly specify java.util.Date in the code.

Or better, try to avoid naming your classes "Date".

Comment: @EthanZ6174: See Puzzle 7 in this sample list from Java Puzzlers - http://www.javapuzzlers.com/java-puzzlers-sampler.pdf. That book is a definite recommend for any Java programmer!

Answer (score 6):

The `toString()` implementation of `java.util.Date` does not depend on the way the class is imported. It always returns a nice formatted date.

The `toString()` you see comes from another class.

Specific import have precedence over wildcard imports.

in this case

```
import other.Date
import java.util.*

new Date();
```

refers to `other.Date` and not `java.util.Date`.

The odd thing is that

```
import other.*
import java.util.*
```

Should give you a compiler error stating that the reference to Date is ambiguous because both `other.Date` and `java.util.Date` matches.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.*;
```

imports everything within java.util including the Date class.

```
import java.util.Date;
```

just imports the Date class.

Doing either of these could not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Your program should work exactly the same with either **import java.util.*;** or **import java.util.Date;**. There has to be something else you did in between.

Comment: thanks for answering the question, and i knew there is no difference between those, unless I named the src "Date.java" ...:(

Answer (score 0):

```
but what I got is something like this: Date@124bbbf  
while I change the import to: import java.util.Date;  
the code works perfectly, why?
```

What do you mean by "works perfectly"? The output of printing a Date object is the same no matter whether you imported java.util.* or java.util.Date. The output that you get when printing objects is the representation of the object by the toString() method of the corresponding class.